# How do I get the ID value from a URL

Tags: taxonomy-terms, uri

example.com:8080/browse?category=137 is my URL for a taxonomy category page.

How am I supposed to take the category ID (137) from that URI?

Answer (score 7):

You can take that id from get array, try

```
print $_GET['category'];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Drupal 7 then you can make use of existing function [drupal_get_query_parameters](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_query_parameters/7)

But also you can use

> `$_GET['category']`

Make sure you use [check_plain()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7) to be sure of save URL values.